# How to return back to cpu from gpu in pytorch?

Tags: python, gpu, cpu, pytorch

I have a text classifier in pytorch and I want to use GPUs to increase running speed.
I have used this part of code to check CUDA and use it:

```
if torch.cuda.device_count() > 1:
    print("Let's use", torch.cuda.device_count(), "GPUs!")
    my_rnn_model = nn.DataParallel(my_rnn_model)
if torch.cuda.is_available():
    my_rnn_model.cuda()
```

Now I want to return back to use cpu (instead of gpu). So I cleared this part of code. But it does’nt work and I receive this error:

```
RuntimeError: cuda runtime error (8) : invalid device function at /opt/conda/conda-bld/pytorch_1503963423183/work/torch/lib/THC/THCTensorCopy.cu:204
```

Would you please guide me how can I return back to cpu running?

Comment: It seems like the compiled binary of PyTorch is having some issues. Can you let us know what GPU are you using and cuda version?

Comment: GPU0 GeForce GT 425M and CUDA 9.0.176. It is too old I'm going to buy a new one.

Comment: I think I have found the reason behind this. Please check my answer

Answer (score 3):

You can set the GPU device that you want to use using:

```
device = torch.device('cuda:0' if torch.cuda.is_available() else 'cpu')
```

And in your case just you can return to CPU using:

```
torch.device('cpu')
```

Comment: Thanks. I should migrate to Pytorch 0.4 for using torch.device. I'm going to check it.

Answer (score 2):

There is a [`.cpu()`](https://pytorch.org/docs/0.3.0/tensors.html#torch.Tensor.cpu) method, equivalent to `.cuda()`, which is available in earlier versions too.

Answer (score 1):

It would seem like your GT 425M has the compute capability of 2.1 which does not met the PyTorch required version (at least 3.0) according to @soumith in this [thread](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/686).

Ergo, it is not possible for you to access some of the GPU-related functions.

You can check the compute capability [here](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-gpus)

More info [here](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/686)